# Direct sum of vector spaces, symbol

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

How do we denote the direct sum of non-orthogonal vector spaces? Is there a symbol for that?

Comment: The symbol $\oplus$ seems to be used for direct sums in general, not only for orthogonal vector spaces.

Comment: I've always liked $\boxplus$ for orthogonal direct sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have that $U,W$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$, such that:

$V = U + W$

$U \cap W = \{0\}$

we say that $V$ is the direct sum of its subspaces $U$ and $W$ and we denote this with $V = U \oplus W$

Comment: I hope you can help me, How can I go, in proving directs sums, from having that ($v_1+v_2=0$ with $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2 \in V_2$ $\implies v_1=v_2=0$) to the fact that $V_1 \cap V_2=\{0\}$ ?

Comment: Is that the full problem? Can you be somewhat clearer because it's false as written. It is true however that $v_1 + v_2 =0 \implies v_1 = v_2 =0$ when we already know that $V_1 \cap V_2 =0$.

Comment: I read it in an exercises it said that, "$V$ is a direct sum of $V_1$ and $V_2$, i.e. $V=V_1+V_2$ and if $v_1+v_2=0$ with $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2 \in V_2$ $\implies v_1=v_2=0$ and is denoted by $V=V_1 \oplus V_2$"

Comment: @FareedAF Ok, now I got some time to answer your question. It is true (unlike I claimed before, sorry for that). I will show that the given condition implies that $0 = V_1 \cap V_2$. For this, take an arbitrary vector $x \in V_1 \cap V_2$. We have to show that $x = 0$. But this is easy: $x+(-x) = 0$ and $x \in V_1, -x \in V_2$ so your condition implies that $0 = x = -x$, and we are done. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you...

Comment: Glad I could help!